# Polynomials that DON'T have certain roots

Tags: polynomials

How many degree $\leq$ $d$ mod($p$) polynomials are there such that $P(a_1),...,P(a_k) \neq 0$ for $k < d$ and $0 < a_1 <...< a_k < p$, all integers?
I considered subtracting out elements from the the set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $d$, but this didn't get me very far.

Comment: A search shows that this is a [homework problem 2c in Berkeley CS 70](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs70/fa13/hw/hw5.pdf)

Comment: The homework was already due.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply the [technique Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/).